# When printing in a div using innerHTML I only see the last option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming so the question may be a little simple for most of the users, here's my question:

I want to use innerHTML to send info to a div tag that I have in my HTML

```
    <div> 
            <input type="number" id="numberBox1">
    </div>
    <div id="display"></div> //I want the info to print inside this div
```

This is my JS code:

```
function asterisks(){
var line= 0 ;
var sum = "" ;
line= parseFloat(document.getElementById("numberBox1").value);

for (var i = 1; i <= line; i++) {
    sum += "*";
    console.log(sum);
}
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sum;
}
```

This is the basic ladder of asterisks that you may already know, using the: 
    console.log(sum); 
In the console I, in fact see the next: (supposing a ladder of 5 asterisks)

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

But in the div in my html I only see the last row, I mean:

```
*****
```

At this  moment I already understood that what its happening is that the information is in fact printing just that it changes so fast that I only get to see the last line...why is happening this? Any help/ideas/comments will be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I think this line 
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sum;
will come into for loop..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do something like this.

```js
function asterisks(){
var line= 0 ;
var sum = "" ;
line= parseFloat(document.getElementById("numberBox1").value);

for (var i = 1; i <= line; i++) {
    sum += "*";
    console.log(sum);
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sum + "<br/>";
}
}
```

```html
<div> 
        <form>
            <input type="number" id="numberBox1">
            <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="asterisks()" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="display"></div> //I want the info to print inside this div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use append in place of innerHTML which will concatenate all your output.